# PhoneGap Playlist issue with iPhone App

Tags: iphone, cordova, playlist

I am creating a small fun application to play some mp3 files into a PhoneGap app 
I have managed to play the audio in the background, many thanks to help on StackOverflow

But now the problem is when the app runs in background, or the app is locked, the next songs does not play. I have written the code to play the next song

=======

```
$(".greyselected").each(function(i) {
if($(this).is(":visible"))
{
activetrackclass = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0];
return;
}
});


$("." + activetrackclass).each(function(i){
if($(this).hasClass("greyselected"))
{
fetchmp3($("." + activetrackclass + ":eq(" + parseInt(i+1) + ")").find(".partistname").text(), $("." + activetrackclass + ":eq(" + parseInt(i+1) + ")").find(".ptrackname").text(), $("." + activetrackclass + ":eq(" + parseInt(i+1) + ")").find(".ptrackurl").text(), $("." + activetrackclass + ":eq(" + parseInt(i+1) + ")").find(".spanduration").text(), "tracklist");

$("." + activetrackclass).removeClass("greyselected");
$("." + activetrackclass + ":eq(" + parseInt(i+1) + ")").addClass("greyselected");

$("#divplayer").slideDown("slow");
return false;
}
});
```

=======

greyselected is the song currently playing
activetrackclass is a variable that holds the class of the track item or track div
fetchmp3 is the function to call the next mp3 file in the list

All mp3 are hosted on a server

When the app is active it plays just fine, but as soon as it goes to background it just plays the song which was actively playing and then stops until the app is made visible again

Would appreciate your valuable help as always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A background task only runs for a period of time, then the OS kills it. If your application is not active then it wont run forever and the ios will stop it after a while.

http://www.macworld.com/article/1164616/how_ios_multitasking_really_works.html

You can declare the support for background playback by specifying `audio` mode in `UIBackgroundModes` in `Info.plist` file. Check page 60 of [iphone programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iphoneappprogrammingguide.pdf) for more detail

You have lot of options to configure the behavior of the audio if you application can use the native code. Check the `Categories Express Audio Roles` in below docs.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875

An old thread from Apple Developer Forum

https://devforums.apple.com/message/264397#264397

Comment: Thanks for the response
I have 2 mp3 files play, first is 30 sec and the other one being 4:00 minutes. They both play completely and then does not move to the next. If you use an app like Pandora / Spotify you can see what I mean - if you select a playlist then even if you tap the middle button or lock the phone, the songs will continue to play.

Comment: check page 60 - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iphoneappprogrammingguide.pdf

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say but Pandora and Spotify does it and even if I set it to loop =true then it keeps playing on and on and on. So not sure what am I doing wrong here

Comment: UIBackgroundModes in Info.plist file is already done
It pushes the current running track to the background but once that is finished it does not play the next. This is whats creating the problem

Comment: it is possible but will require some native stuff to do - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875 - check the `Categories Express Audio Roles`

Comment: Did not find anything fruitful to be true :(

Comment: this does follow the same thing mentioned in the doc - https://devforums.apple.com/message/264397#264397

Comment: Does anyone know what the actual solution to this is?